# Node-Webkit: How to minimize the window?

Tags: node-webkit

I am wondering how to minimize the window. The documentation is kinda confusing.
Closing the window is no problem but minimizing won't work this way:

`document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.close();
    }, false);`

The same goes for this method:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();

document.getElementById('minimize').addEventListener('click', function() {
win.window.minimize(); }, false);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation in https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window#wiki-windowminimize call

```
win.minimize();
```

instead

Comment: I know this part, but it doesn't work. The 'win' in win.minimize is a variable. It is defined above in the documentation
`var win = gui.Window.get();`

but when I tried it, I always received an error. I don't know why but suddenly its working-.- Maybe I wrote something wrong..

so, before the function I have to define both variables
`var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();`

Comment: "so, before the function I have to define both variables"
Looking at that little piece of code I don't see why. `win` should be part of the closure of your event handler function.

Are you sure that you are not "shadowing" that symbol with a different definition of `win`?